# Reading offsets from file

Tags: .net, vb.net

I do not know how to read offsets (& H123 etc.) with ini files. Here's my function:

```
<DllImport("kernel32", EntryPoint:="GetPrivateProfileString")>
Private Shared Function ReadINI(
    ByVal Sektion As String, ByVal Key As String, ByVal StandartVal As String,
    ByVal Result As StringBuilder, ByVal Size As Int32, ByVal Dateiname As String) As Int32
End Function

Public Function read(Sektion As String, Parameter As String)
    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(1024)
    ReadINI(Sektion, Parameter, "", sb, sb.Capacity, ConfigPath)
    Return sb.ToString
End Function
```

Comment: Why are you P/Invoking to `GetPrivateProfileString` at all? INI files aren't terribly complicated; it seems much simpler (and safer) to simply read the thing in managed code and parse all the "setting=value" lines. True, this may fail for some ini files that use obscure syntax, but that may very well not be an issue. (And I'm assuming you already know no *new* applications should be using ini files and you need to read them for compatibility with some existing application.)